# How to enable path folder in mac terminal

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

As You see when I put command "pwd" I'm in folder:

> MacBook-Grzeg% pwd 
>   /Users/Grzeg/ticket_managment

But my terminal still show only that's:

> MacBook-Grzeg%

Now as you can see  I have a short path in my terminal. How do I turn on a full path to the folder where I am. **Or how to see folder where I'm like this:**

> MacBook-Grzeg: ticket_managment Grzeg$

Comment: [This excellent resource](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The default prompt in OS X is:

```
\h:\W \u\$
computername:foldername username$
```

Set your prompt to this by placing the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PS1="\h:\W \u\$"
```